# How to disable automatic WebMail Form Resize of Text Input fields by browsers like FireFox 4, Safari & Chrome?

Tags: firefox, forms, input, textbox, resize

Recently upgraded to the awesome FireFox 4.
However, I would like to disable the automatically embedded resize function that brwosers automatically assign to text input fields, as I already have my own resizing functions...

How to I disable automatic Form Resize of text input fields done by browsers like FireFox 4, Safari & Chrome??

Any suggestions how to disable this feature would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set in its style (or your whole stylesheet) "resize:none"
Example:

```
textarea { resize:none }
```